# How to get the text inside a span tag which is inside another tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I get the value of all the tags that have class="no-wrap text-right circulating-supply"? What I used was:

```
text=[ ]

text=(soup.find_all(class_="no-wrap text-right circulating-supply"))
```

Output of `text[0]`:

```
'\n\n17,210,662\nBTC\n'
```

I just want to extract the numeric value.

Example of one instance:

```
<td class="no-wrap text-right circulating-supply" data-sort="17210662.0">
            <span data-supply="17210662.0">
             <span data-supply-container="">
              17,210,662
             </span>
             <span class="hidden-xs">
              BTC
             </span>
            </span>
           </td>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case all elements have similar HTML structure try below to get required output:

```
texts = [node.text.strip().split('\n')[0] for node in soup.find_all(class_="no-wrap text-right circulating-supply")]
```

Comment: I am getting this error

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Are you sure that `text[0]` returns you text? I guess `soup.find_all()` should return something like a WebElement object. Check updated answer

Comment: you are right, I forgot to add .text 
this works.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This might look like an overkill , You could use use regex to extract numbers

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<td class="no-wrap text-right circulating-supply" data-sort="17210662.0">
            <span data-supply="17210662.0">
            <span data-supply-container="">
            17,210,662
            </span>
            <span class="hidden-xs">
            BTC
            </span>
            </span>
        </td>"""
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
coin_value =  [re.findall('(\d+)', node.text.replace(',','')) for node in soup.find_all(class_="no-wrap text-right circulating-supply")]
print coin_value
```

prints

```
[[u'17210662']]
```